# mysql query to get comment count on category via articles via comments

Tags: mysql

If the title isn't helping, I'll try to clarify.

I have the following:

```
Category    Article        Comment
--------    -----------    ----------
id          id             id
name        category_id    article_id
```

Assuming I have three Categories (`fiction`, `essays`, `journalism`) and a mess of articles and comments, how can I get a total comment count for each of the three categories? I know it would be easy enough to via loops (I'm working in Ruby), but I'd much prefer to use a single MySql query. Or as close to as possible.

I checked SO for an answer, but all I found was a lot of "Get total comments on an article," without the categories on top complicating things. Maybe I'm just missing the right terms?

Anyway, thanks!

Brief edit: added the `name` field in category. This is where `fiction`, `essays`, `journalism` would go.

Comment: Which field is for your Categories the `id` or the `category_id`? You can use aggregate function `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`. See example [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

Comment: Which field has the values of the Categories (i.e. fiction, essays, journalism). Is it `id` or the `category_id`, is what I am asking for. Sorry if you misunderstood my question or I haven't worded it the right way.

Comment: No, I got you. Edit in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this SQL Statement.

```
SELECT `name`, COUNT(*) as commentcount
FROM Category
INNER JOIN Article ON Article.category_id=Category.id
INNER JOIN Comment ON Comment.article_id=Article.id
GROUP BY `name`
```

Comment: I'll have to check the math, but this appears to work! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered sub-selecting the total comments by articles and then have a parent select link up the category name. ie.

```
SELECT category.name, a.comment_count FROM
    (
    SELECT article.category_id AS cat_id, COUNT(1) AS comment_count
        FROM article INNER JOIN comment
            ON article.id = comment.article_id
        GROUP BY article.category_id
    ) AS a,
    category
WHERE category.id = a.cat_id
```

Comment: This also works. I don't know enough mysql to guess which answer works better, but this one seems more complicated? But also maybe more versatile, depending on what a person was looking for. Say if I wanted to figure average time elapsed between comments, by category?

Answer (score 0):

You could use *COUNT()* with *GROUP BY* to count how many per each category.

```
SELECT `name`, COUNT(*) as CategoryCount
FROM tbl
GROUP BY `name`
```

See [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) or this [one](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-group-by.php) for more details.